# AngularJS - How to load a service from other app

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service

I have this angular code:

This is my **controller**:

```
MyApp.controller('vtCustomerController', function ($scope, messageBus, customerDetails, $http, $q) {


   $scope.loadCustomerDetail = function (customerID) {
        customerDetails.loadCustomerDetails(customerID);

    };


});
```

This is my **service**:

```
MyApp.factory('customerDetails', function($rootScope,$http, $q) {

        var customer = {};

        getCustomer = function()
        {
            return customer;
        };

       loadCustomerDetails = function(customerID) {
             $http.post('/customer/data/getsingleexpanded',
                   {'customer':customerID})
                    .success(function(data,status, headers, config){
                        angular.copy(data, customer);
                    })
                    .error(function(data,status, headers, config){
                        console.log(status);
                    });   
        };
});
```

And this is an **autocomplete** method:

```
angular.module('text-autocomplete',[])
                .directive('text-autocomplete', function(){
                    return {
                                require: '^ngModel',
                                restrict: 'A',
                                scope:{
                                    ngModel:'=',
                                    datasource:'=',
                                    minlength:'=',
                                    itemid:'='
                                },
                                link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {

                                        elem.autocomplete({
                                            autoFocus : !_.isUndefined(attr.autofocus)? true : false,
                                            open: function(event,ui){console.log('autocomplete open message received')},
                                            source: function(request,response){
                                                    scope.datasource(ctrl.$viewValue)
                                                         .then(function(result){
                                                             console.log('data source then function called');
                                                             console.log(result.data);
                                                                response(result.data)});
                                                },
                                            minLength: scope.minlength,
                                            select: function(event,ui){
                                                console.log('autofocus select called');
                                                console.log(ui);
                                                    //-1 indicates item not found
                                                 //store the information in the control. 
                                                 if(ui.item.value != '-1')
                                                 {
                                                         scope.ngModel = ui.item.label;
                                                         if(attr.itemid)
                                                         {
                                                             scope.itemid = ui.item.value;
                                                         }

                                                 }
                                                 else if(ctrl.$viewValue != '')
                                                 {
                                                     scope.ngModel = ctrl.$viewValue;
                                                     scope.itemid = 0;
                                                 }
                                                 else
                                                 {
                                                     console.log('setting the account number to blank');
                                                     scope.ngModel = '';
                                                     scope.itemid = -1;                                                     
                                                 }
                                                 scope.$apply();

                                                 return false;
                                                },
                                             focus: function(event,ui){
                                                return false;
                                                },
                                             close: function(event,ui){
                                                 console.log('autocomplete close called');
                                                 console.log(ui);
                                                }
                                          });



                                }
                    };
                });
```

What i need to do is, in the **select** in the autocomplete, which is when you click an item ) call the **customerDetails.loadCustomerDetails** method (from the service). But it's in other **app**, right?

Is there any way to do this? Or maybe, a better way?

Comment: Please note that tags are not keywords.  Stuffing the tag list full of the same words that are in your question (app, directive, service) will not help categorize it.  Tags also stand alone.  That is, you can't combine multiple tags to create a single concept.  The tags `[angularjs]` and `[directive]` together aren't the same thing as the single `[angularjs-directive]` tag, for example.  **Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** - This only addresses the OP's misunderstanding of the problem, while @TongShen seems to have offered a solution to the *actual* problem.

I think you're conflating the concept of an *app* with that of a *module*.

Apps would tend to need some extra layer (e.g. an API) to communicate with one another, so if what you demonstrated were apps, then yes, you might have a problem.

Instead, your code demonstrates the use of *modules*, which can be used extensively with Angular to help segment and encapsulate your code. Provided that each module is interfaced properly through use of dependency injection, they can access one another.

Here is a simple demonstration, loosely patterned from your code:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['otherApp']);
var anotherModule = angular.module('otherApp', []);

myApp.factory('MyFactory', function(){
  var stuff = {};

  stuff.doSomething = function(){
    console.log('just did something');
  }

  return stuff;
});

anotherModule.directive('myDirective', function(MyFactory){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(){
      MyFactory.doSomething();
    }  
  }
});
```

... and you can see that the `console.log` does fire in [this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/CfGrV096EDKVhTOgY2zZ?p=preview).

Comment: After 3 hours of investigation (on my own) I didn't solve the problem. With your answer, I did it in 10minutes. Thank you so much !!

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the `loadCustomerDetails` function (from the controller scope) into the directive.

Define like this in the scope of your directive:

```
scope:{
    ngModel:'=',
    datasource:'=',
    minlength:'=',
    itemid:'=',
    autoComplete: '&'
},
```

And update your directive usage in the HTML to add:

```
<...... text-autocomplete ...... auto-complete="loadCustomerDetails($customerId)">
```

When you want to call the function in the directive, just call:

```
scope.autoComplete({$customerId: customerId});
```

This should work.

P.S.

You may say an app is a module, but not all modules are apps. Sometimes you can make modules that are only packages of services, resources, or whatever. Services or functions from different modules can be used together very well in one app as long as you specify the dependencies correctly.